# Category blog view - filter by tags

Tags: tags, category-blog, filter

Joomla 5. I am using the category blog view to show all the articles in a category.

I have set up tags and applied them to the articles to enable some kind of filtering on the same page/view?

Ideally I wanted a drop down list. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

It would be great to have a tags filter module for the Category Blog view in the Joomla core but sadly this is not currently the case.

The excellent [Tags - Filter](https://extensions.joomla.org/extension/tags-filter) third party module from Rene Kreijveld provides filtering by tags and does not interfere with the category blog layout but this extension has unfortunately not been updated for Joomla 4 or Joomla 5.

There are a few other options that are not quite as elegant solutions:

1. Create a drop down list or buttons with links like this:

   `index.php?option=com_content&view=category&layout=blog&id=9&filter_tag[0]=6&Itemid=125`

Update the blog ID, menu ID and tag ID as needed. In the example above, "6" is the ID of the tag you want to filter on.

This works on Joomla 4 and I assume Joomla 5 works the same way.

2. Brian Teeman has some tips on implementing a tags filter in Joomla 4 using template overrides at https://brian.teeman.net/joomla/897-joomla-tags-as-custom-filters and this might also apply to Joomla 5.
3. There are many free and paid third party extensions that enable you to filter by tags but they tend to also override the article layout which you may not want. Examples include:

- [JFilters](https://extensions.joomla.org/extension/jfilters) from blue-coder.com Component/Module/Plugin
- [Minitek Wall](https://extensions.joomla.org/extension/minitek-wall-pro) Component/Module
- [Minitek Responsive Grid for Articles](https://extensions.joomla.org/extension/responsive-grid-for-articles) Module
- [JT Content Filter](https://extensions.joomla.org/extension/jt-content-filter) Module